# How do you remove the space at the bottom of Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, macvim

I recently started using MacVim and was wondering how I can change the scroll behaviour of Vim so that when the scroll bar reaches the end of the code, it doesn't go any further (just something that irks me since other text editors I've used aren't like this and if I quickly try scrolling to the bottom it goes past the last lines). Right now, there are always some blank lines between the last line with code and the end of the editor. Is there any particular reason why that is?

(This is what I'm referring to):

[image]

Comment: you mean the lines starting with `~`?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean

Comment: that's part of *vim way of life*. It allows you to edit the last line of the file in the middle of the view port or to not be bothered by the rest of the file when writing long documents or files. Because you're not supposed to use the mouse with vim, it should not be a problem. ;)

Comment: the vim-way of scolling down quickly (thats what you intentionally wanted to do) is pressing uppercase `G` in normal mode. i recommend to use the shortcuts, you are incredible much faster with them then scrolling the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to control the viewport of the buffer is an intrinsic part of Vim; I'm not aware of any option that could influence that. With the cursor on [one of the] last line[s] in the buffer, you can use the `[count]zb` (*redraw with current / `[count]` line at the bottom*) command to get the layout you desire.

You might be able to automate that on an `:autocmd CursorMoved * ...` trigger, but figuring out whether the current viewport requires such correction (considering things like `:set wrap`) in a programmatic way might be quite difficult.

Answer (score 1):

At least one reason for why it's like this is this:

There's a command for scrolling so that the cursor is at the top of the screen: `zt`. If your cursor is on the last line in the file, the behaviour you describe is necessary for this to work.

You ask for a way to disable this though, and I do not know any way to this.
 An answer to this question on superuser states that it is indeed not possible to do:
https://superuser.com/questions/381406/dont-let-vim-scroll-below-bottom-line